# How can i get the identifier of a draggable element by using stop event in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following code

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="_01">1° item</div>
    <div id="_02">2° item</div>
    <div id="_03">3° item</div>
    <div id="_04">4° item</div>
</div>
```

So in my js code

```
$("#container div").draggable({
    stop:function(e, ui) {

    }});
```

What i have to put in stop event in order to get the identifier of a draggable element ?

regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#container div").draggable({
    stop:function(e, ui) {
       alert("id=" + $(this).attr("id");
    }});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$(this)  // this should be the current element
```